# Set a delay between For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i made this function with jquery and i want to set a delay between every loop i tried to setInterval inside the for loop but it doesn't work .

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
      for(let i =1;i <=6 ;i++){
      $('#steps_icon-'+i).each( function(){
              var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
              var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
              if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'
                ,'transform':'translateY(0px)',
                },2000);
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

what this function does when you scroll it will make an icon appear but i want to set delay between every icon to appear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to make it wait. Bu it is asynchronous so you should use async-await keywords.

````
// Function to make program wait
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Your code
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll( async function(){ // Added async keyword here
    for(let i =1;i <=6 ;i++){
    await sleep(200) // Added this line
    $('#steps_icon-'+i).each( function(){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
              $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'
              ,'transform':'translateY(0px)',
              },2000);
          }
      });
    }
  });
});
```
````

Comment: wow it works great , but do you know why transform translate Y isn't working in my function ?

Comment: I could not see the reason at a glance. If you can share a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I can play around and maybe find the error.

Comment: i will try to make it work because it's on a server it won't work on jsfiddle :(

Comment: i made it work with this line :

$('#steps_icon-'+i).css({'transform': 'translateY(0px)'})

and inside css like this :

[id^="steps_icon"]{
  
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}